# Issue with instanceof Checks Failing for Dynamically Imported Classes in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I dynamically import classes for a Discord bot, but I'm encountering an issue where instanceof checks are failing at runtime, even though everything seems correct in the setup.

Environment:

Node.js version: 20.9.0
TypeScript version: 5.2.2
Project setup: Discord bot using discord.js

**Issue**:
`instanceof` checks are returning `false` for instances that should be of a certain class. The issue occurs in the runtime environment, despite the TypeScript compilation showing no errors.

**Code Overview:**
I have a setup where commands and events for a Discord bot are dynamically loaded from files. The main class structure is as follows:

`ReadableCommandObject` and `ReadableEventObject` are base classes.

Specific commands like `Ping extends ReadableCommandObject`.
The `ObjectFetcher.read` method dynamically imports these command classes.

**Ping Command Example:**

Here's an example of a command class:

```js
import { type CommandInteraction, SlashCommandBuilder, type CacheType } from 'discord.js';
import ReadableCommandObject from '../../../../utilities/ObjectFetcher/ReadableCommandObject';


class Ping extends ReadableCommandObject {
    data: SlashCommandBuilder;
    execute: (interaction: CommandInteraction<CacheType>) => Promise<any>;

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies pong!');

        this.execute = async (interaction: CommandInteraction<CacheType>) => {
            return await interaction.reply('Pong!');
        };
    }

    getReadableData (): unknown {
        return {
            data: this.data,
            execute: this.execute
        };
    };
}

export default Ping;
```

**Object Fetching Method:**

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-extraneous-class */
import type IReadableObject from './IReadableObject';

class ObjectFetcher {
    static async read (filePath: string): Promise<IReadableObject> {
        try {
            if (!filePath || filePath.length === 0) {
                throw new Error('The file path provided is empty');
            }

            const readableObjectClass = await require(filePath).default;
            const readableObject = new readableObjectClass();
            return readableObject;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('There was an error while fetching the object: ', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-extraneous-class */

export default ObjectFetcher;
```

**Issue Replication:**

During runtime, when I try to check if an imported object is an instance of `ReadableCommandObject` or `ReadableEventObject`, the check fails:

```js
// Asynchronously crawls specified directories for command and event JS files, dynamically loading and processing each found file.
const objectFetchResolver = async () => {
    const filePaths: string[] = ['core/models/commands', 'core/models/events'];
    for (const filePath of filePaths) {
        const crawler = new FileCrawler(path.join(__dirname, filePath), '.js', true, true);
        const objectFilePaths = await crawler.crawl();
        for (const objectFilePath of objectFilePaths) {
            const objectInFile = await ObjectFetcher.read(objectFilePath);
            if (objectInFile instanceof ReadableCommandObject) {
                console.log('Entered in ReadableCommandObject');
                commandObjectAdderModerator(objectInFile, objectFilePath);
            } else if (objectInFile instanceof ReadableEventObject) {
                console.log('Entered in ReadableEventObject');
                eventObjectAdderModerator(objectInFile, objectFilePath);
            } else {
                console.log('Nothing matched');
            }
        }
    };
};
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Nothing matched
Nothing matched
Nothing matched
```

**Additional Context:**

Interestingly, when I run the same code in a debugger (e.g., using Visual Studio Code's debugger or Node.js's `--inspect`), the `instanceof` checks work as expected, and I get the correct data. However, when running the application normally (outside of a debugger), the `instanceof` checks fail. This behavior suggests that the issue might be related to the environment or the execution context.

[image]

**Specific Behavior in Debugger:**

When debugging, `objectInFile instanceof ReadableCommandObject` returns `true`.
In normal execution, the same check returns `false`.
Question:
What could be causing the discrepancy in the behavior of `instanceof` checks between the debugger and normal runtime? Are there specific aspects of the Node.js execution environment or TypeScript's compilation process that might behave differently in a debugging context?

- Ensured that file paths and exports are correct.
- Checked and recompiled TypeScript code.
- Inspected the compiled JavaScript code for any anomalies.
- Verified Node.js and TypeScript versions.

## Solution Update

After exploring various potential solutions and considering the feedback and suggestions, I decided to shift my approach from using instanceof to leveraging TypeScript's type guards and interfaces. This change aligns more closely with TypeScript's design patterns and has resolved the issues I was facing.

### New Approach:

**TypeScript Type Guards**: Implemented custom type guards to check the type of objects dynamically. This method provides a more robust and TypeScript-oriented way to ensure that the objects are of the correct type.

Interfaces and Type Checking: Used interfaces to define the structure of my command and event objects. This approach not only makes the code more readable and maintainable but also harnesses the full power of TypeScript's static type checking.

Example Implementation:

Here's a brief example of how I implemented this:

```js
import { type SlashCommandBuilder, type CommandInteraction } from 'discord.js';

interface ICommand {
    type: 'command'
    data: SlashCommandBuilder
    execute: (interaction: CommandInteraction) => Promise<any>
}

export default ICommand;

import type IReadableObject from '../readable-object';
import type ICommand from '../commands/command';

function isCommand (obj: IReadableObject): obj is ICommand {
    return obj.type === 'command';
}

export default isCommand;

// Usage
const loadObjects = async () => {
    const filePaths = ['core/models/commands', 'core/models/events'];

    for (const file of filePaths) {
        const crawler = new FileCrawler(path.join(__dirname, file), '.js', true, true);
        const objectFilePaths = await crawler.crawl();
        for (const objectFilePath of objectFilePaths) {
            const object: ReadableObject = await ObjectFetcher.read(objectFilePath);
            readableObjectHandler(object);
        }
    }
};

// So here I just handle the type of each and accordingly assign the adder moderator
const readableObjectHandler = (readableObject: ReadableObject): void => {
    if (isCommand(readableObject)) {
        commandObjectAdderModerator(readableObject);
    } else if (isEvent(readableObject)) {
        eventObjectAdderModerator(readableObject);
    }
};
```

This method has effectively resolved the runtime issues I was experiencing with instanceof checks, and it fits more naturally into the TypeScript ecosystem.